# nested query in sequelize mysql to get upvote and downvote count

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to get upvote and downvote for a **Post** which has **Answer** table associated and separate **Votes** table associated to **Answer**

```
const posts = await Posts.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Answers,
        include: [{
          attributes: { 
              include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("id")), "votesCount"]] 
          },
          model: Votes, attributes: []
        }]
    }]
});
```

Here is my **Votes** schema

```
const Votes = sequelize.define('votes', {
    id:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement:true,
        allowNull:false,
        primaryKey:true
      },
      answerId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
         references: {
          model: 'answers',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
         references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      voteType: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull:false },
      createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
      updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE
})
```

**voteType** true means upvote and false means downvote

Is there any way to get the results with Sequelize?

Expecting something like that,

```
[{
            "id": 1,
            "userId": 15,
            "title": "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "postId": 1,
                    "userId": 33,
                    "ans": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia",
                }
            ],
            votes: {
                upVote: 5,
                downVote: 1
            }
        },]
```

Comment: It seems you need to use `Sequelize.literal` to get both counts using subqueries

Comment: @Anatoly Can u help me with a example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Sequelize.literal` to get both counts by using subqueries:

```
const posts = await Posts.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Answers,
        include: [{
          attributes: { 
              include: [
  [Sequelize.literal("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Votes WHERE answerId=answer.id AND Votes.voteType=true)"), "upVote"],
  [Sequelize.literal("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Votes WHERE answerId=answer.id AND Votes.voteType=false)"), "downVote"]
          ] 
          }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, You save my day